# Simple GPU miner with long pooling C++

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-software, c++

I want to write own GPU miner, but I can't find any simple solution (cgminer and RPC miner are big projects with many useless to me functions). I need the sources of only one GPU miner with long pooling, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

[This is the simplest miner I know of:](https://github.com/jgarzik/pyminer)

> pyminer
>
> This is a 'getwork' CPU mining client for bitcoin.
>
> It is pure-python, and therefore very, very slow.  The purpose is to
>   provide a reference implementation of a miner, for study.

This doesn't support long polling, but there's a spec for that [here](https://deepbit.net/longpolling.php).

[:)](http://xkcd.com/541/)